# Simulate MouseEvent, KeyEvent, etc

Tags: java, swing, events, user-interface

I'm working on an application running on Java in a headless environment. I'm handling all input and output through custom classes; my root `JPanel` is drawing to a `BufferedImage` which is then presented to the user. However, I'm having trouble passing `MouseEvents` to allow the `JPanel` and its children to handle them.

Currently, the constructor of my main class, a child of `JPanel`, uses:

```
this.enableInputMethods(true);
this.enableEvents(~0);
```

Then, in `onMouseDown(MouseEvent e)` and friends (which *do* get executed):

```
dispatchEvent(e);
```

I've also tried `processEvent(e)` and `processMouseEvent(e)`, but to no avail.

I'm generating the `MouseEvent` using the `JPanel` subclass as the source, and `MOUSE_PRESSED` and its friends as the ID.

Is there anything else I can do either in the constructor or the event handler that will allow the `JPanel` to process the event as a normal event, passing it off to its children and firing any `ActionEvents` and focus changes?

Comment: Why are you using current time (which returns a long) as the MouseEvent's ID? That seems questionable to me. And what do you mean by a "headless" environment?

Comment: "Headless" environment is a standard term, it means UI elements won't display on a screen. They render into the `BufferedImage` just fine though. Also, current time as the ID will generate unique IDs as long as the user does not generate events less than 1 ms apart, which the system prohibits.

Comment: I didn't think that the MouseEvent ID should be unique but rather should be a bit map that reflects which MouseButton was pressed as well as the current event state. Perhaps I am referring to a different ID than you. I'm referring to the `id` property that is first defined in the AWTEvent class, a class that is one of the ancestors to MouseEvent and which is queried by calling `MouseEvent#getID()`.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that I'm generating the `MouseEvents` completely from scratch. I have no `MouseEvent` that I can call `getID()` on in the first place. Also, I attempted to generate the `MouseEvent` using `MOUSE_PRESSED` and its friends, but got the same result---no action.

Comment: I know, but if you're simulating MouseEvents, you'd better create one that has an ID that reflects the state you desire the event to have. This probably won't solve your problem, but using a random number for this is still not a good idea.

Comment: Ok. Reading the docs, you're right in that the ID represents the type of event. I've updated my code.

Comment: Does your `onMouseDown(MouseEvent e)` ever get executed?

Comment: are you using `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent();` to generate events?

Comment: @Sanjay: Yes, onMouseDown gets executed; no, I'm not using the Toolkit to generate them, but the constructor.

Comment: I tried `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent();` and hooking into them with `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(this, ALLBITS);`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a workaround that I'm currently implementing, manually creating the `ActionEvents` and keeping track of the currently focused component. I'm working on passing `MouseEvents` down to child components at the moment but here's what I've got.

```
Component c = findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
if(c!=null){
    ActionEvent ae = new ActionEvent(c,ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,"");
    ActionListener[] listeners = c.getListeners(ActionListener.class);
    for(ActionListener l:listeners){
        l.actionPerformed(ae);
    }
    if(c.isFocusable()) setFocusedComponent(c);
}
```

Admittedly, it's pretty messy, but in absence of a better path to pursue I have to implement it this way.